# FBSDKShareLinkContent is not setting the contentDescription and contentTitle

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, sdk, share

I am trying to share a link on the Facebook using `FBSDKShareLinkContent`.

I have set the URL, description and title. SDK is automatically populates the title and description by information scraped from the `contentURL`.

But I want to set custom title and description that I have given in code. Is there anyway to avoid this behaviour?

```
  FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
[content setContentTitle:@"Testing title"];
[content setContentDescription:@"Testing description."];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.co.in/"]];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
withContent:content
delegate:nil];
```

Comment: Correct. We use the title and description from the og-tags on the page

Comment: Is there anyway to set a custom title and description other than scraped items from site?

Comment: Oh..It is sad. Is there any way to share link on FB with custom title and description.

Comment: It is still possible when the post is made via API, but that of course requires users to login and grant permission. But in general, that should rather not be attempted in the first place. By having a “static” thumbnail, title and description, it is easier for users to identify content they have seen already. People might feel rather cheated, when they get the same stuff presented in different “disguises”.

Comment: @WizKid In my Android application, I can set custom title and description for the  ShareLinkContent for the same link. Problem is arise only in iOS sdk.

Comment: Setting the contentTitle and contentDescription explicitly in code should override the scraped content from og tags. What version of the Facebook app and Facebook SDK are you using? I cannot reproduce this on my side. Using the RPS sample app to share a link (with an overridden title) works as expected for me.

Comment: if I remove the og:description tag from my site, I still can't set the title programmatically in the iOS app...

Answer (score 15):

I've faced a same problem and found out one workaround - direct setting mode of FBSDKShareDialog instance to FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedWeb.

```
FBSDKShareDialog* dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedWeb;
dialog.shareContent = content;
dialog.fromViewController = self;
[dialog show];
```

It displays the feed dialog in a UIWebView within the app with preview of your post with right title and description.

Comment: +one for this line dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedWeb. This does the trick.

Comment: FBSDKShareDialogModeNative also works -- and I think the Native mode is nicer than "FeedWeb." However, if you do use FBSDKShareDialogModeNative, add an "if (dialogue.canShow)" call, because the [dialogue show] will fail silently if the user doesn't have the Facebook app installed. The if statement gives you a chance to assign a different dialog.mode, then show.

Answer (score 2):

FBSDKShareDialogMode sets to FeedBrowser resolves my issue

```
let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
dialog.fromViewController = self
dialog.shareContent = shareLink
dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.FeedBrowser
dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it works perfectly on my virtual device, until I setted up Facebook account in setting of phone. After I set that, every time that I want to open dialog was opened default iOS social share dialog.
Delete your account, if it exist in settings, or just install FB application, in documentation I saw that we need FB app for sharing.

If this will not help, you can always use Social Share framework of iOS, here is the example.

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/

Hope this will help, by the way, today I stack on this problems too, now every thing working great with this Social Sharing framework of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Use **quote** property of FBSDKShareLinkContent instead

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *linkContent = [FBSDKShareLinkContent new];
linkContent.quote = @"your quote";

FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [FBSDKShareDialog new];
shareDialog.shareContent = linkContent;
```

`setContentTitle` and `setContentDescription` have been deprecated from Graph API 2.9.
For more information, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_deprecations