# FBSDKShareLinkContent is not tagging people with the peopleIDs I set

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, share

I'm following the Facebook SDK documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/share-button and the people I tag via `peopleIDs` are not tagged in the post that I share.

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Facebook_Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg/2880px-Facebook_Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg"];
NSURL *contentURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook"];

FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [FBSDKShareLinkContent new];
content.contentURL = contentURL;
content.contentTitle = @"My Share Title";
content.contentDescription = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
content.imageURL = imageURL;
content.peopleIDs = @[@"10206439771816757"];
content.placeID = @"166793820034304";
content.ref = @"myRefId";
```

I modified the sample code to use an ID for a person who is a friend and they are not getting tagged.  How do I tag friends?

There's some weirdness going on with this API call, as revealed in this other SO post, [FBSDKShareLinkContent is not setting the contentDescription and contentTitle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916591/fbsdksharelinkcontent-is-not-setting-the-contentdescription-and-contenttitle), so I'm wondering if there is some trick to getting people tagged.

**Update**:
It turns out the tagging works if you use the `FBSDKShareButton` to share the url.  However, I want to share and tag people using a `FBSDKShareDialog`.  I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this should work, but please file a bug report on developers.facebook.com/bugs, include code for both the share button and share dialog so they can reproduce easily and assign if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and it appeared to me that tagging people is only supported when using the native app to display the share dialog.

My solution was to try `FBSDKShareDialogModeNative` first, and otherwise fall back to the default `FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic`:

```
- (void)shareLinkContent:(FBSDKShareLinkContent *)linkContent fromViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
    dialog.fromViewController = viewController;
    dialog.shareContent = linkContent;

    // Try the native mode first. If it isn't supported,
    //  fall back on automatic mode.
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;
    if (![dialog canShow]) {
        dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic;
    }

    [dialog show];
}
```